# Async post to Amazon's SQS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'd like to send messages to Amazon's SQS in a "launch and forget" mode (it's OK for some messages to get lost).

Today, I use this sync code:

```
webClient.UploadValues(uri, "POST", data);
```

Since this is going to be heavily used, I want to change this to an async method.

Is there a way to do this (either using plain .net or AWS SDK)?

Comment: Have you looked at `HttpClient`?

Comment: Yuval, I get 404 from AWS when using HttpClient PostAsync.

Comment: Are the URL's identical?

Comment: The same. I think the reason is when using HttpClient, I pass a StringContent which contains a json - perhaps it's a content-type which they don't expect.

Comment: 404 usually means "we can't find this address you're looking for". That, or the people at the server side did a poor job of returning proper status codes.

Comment: Yuval, that's the way SQS behaves. When changing content type to x-www-form-urlencoded, I get 403.

Comment: Found the reason UploadValuesAsync didn't work: It was missing a content-type header http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html#POSTRequests

Comment: Nice. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason UploadValuesAsync didn't work: It was missing a content-type header:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html#POSTRequests